# FIREWALL vs PACKET Sniffer

Tags: firewall, packet-sniffers

I m new to the computer networking.
I came across two terms FIREWALL and packet sniffer.

To me the operation wise both appears to be same.Please clarify

Comment: Where did you find definitions of these where it made the operations sound similar?

Answer (score 2):

**Firewall**

A firewall can either be software-based or hardware-based and is used to help keep a network secure. Its primary objective is to control the incoming and outgoing network traffic by analyzing the data packets and determining whether it should be allowed through or not

**Sniffer**

A packet analyzer (also known as a network analyzer, protocol analyzer or packet sniffer, or for particular types of networks, an Ethernet sniffer or wireless sniffer) is a computer program or a piece of computer hardware that can intercept and log traffic passing over a digital network or part of a network

By the way you can also check wikipedia...